# Finding external ray of radius

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]
Since all radiI are equal in length I could find the radius part but the external part of radius I couldn't find it
I will be thankful for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pythagorean theorem:

$MB=\sqrt{MN^2-NB^2}=\sqrt{(8+5)^2-5^2}=12$

$NC=\sqrt{MN^2-MC^2}=\sqrt{(8+5)^2-8^2}=\sqrt{105}$

Comment: I didn't realise that! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what is  pythagorean theorem?

Comment: Of course. I just didn't realise that I can solve it by pythagoreas